# Fancybox: access content from event callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox with HTML content.

```
$( '#rename' ).fancybox(    
    {
        content: $( '#rename-container' ).html(),
        afterShow: 
            function()
            {
                // some code here 
            }
    } 
);
```

***rename-container*** is a div element with inner HTML. How can I access the content with jQuery (or with something else) **in afterShow handler function**?

E.g. the content contains an *input element*, I have to set focus.

Answer (score 2):

In afterShow we can access by recalling to **$('.fancybox-inner')**.

```
$( '#rename' ).fancybox(    
    {
        content: $( '#rename-container' ).html(),
        afterShow: 
            function( el )
            {
                var overlay = $('.fancybox-inner');
                var newNameInput = overlay.find( 'input' );                     
                newNameInput.focus(); 
            }
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be easier to target directly the element `#rename-container` via `href` in your html like

```
<a id="rename" class="fancybox" href="#rename-container">open fancybox</a>
```

then just `focus` on any element using its selector like

```
$("#rename").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $("#myInput").focus();
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nk7dY/)**